# SQL query to unpivot and union for multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot, cross-apply

I'm trying to achieve the following result...

input, table A

```
-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+----------+----------+---------+
sub  |   c_f  |  type  | F_G | layer | dec_2020 | jan_2021 | feb_2021
-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+----------+----------+---------+
A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  50   |  d_val_1 | j_val_1  | f_val_1
A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  60   |  d_val_2 | j_val_2  | f_val_2
A600 |  future| Analog |  G  |  32   |  d_val_3 | j_val_3  | f_val_3
-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+----------+----------+---------+
```

I would obtain this output

```
-----------+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+----------+
month_year | sub |   c_f  |  type  | F_G | layer | values   
-----------+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+----------+
dec_2020   |A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  50   |  d_val_1 
dec_2020   |A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  60   |  d_val_2 
dec_2020   |A600 |  future| Analog |  G  |  32   |  d_val_3 
jan_2021   |A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  50   |  j_val_1  
jan_2021   |A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  60   |  j_val_2    
jan_2021   |A600 |  future| Analog |  G  |  32   |  j_val_3   
feb_2021   |A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  50   |  f_val_1  
feb_2021   |A600 |  Core  | Analog |  F  |  60   |  f_val_2
feb_2021   |A600 |  future| Analog |  G  |  32   |  f_val_3
-----+--------+--------+-----+-------+----------+----------+
```

I'm trying to use cross apply and I can create the column "month_year" but I don't know how to merge "values" in the last column.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is basically `apply`:

```
select v.month_year, a.sub, a.c_f, a.type, a.F_G, a.layer, v.value
from a cross apply
     (values ('dec_2020', a.dec_2020),
             ('jan_2021', a.jan_2021),
             ('feb_2021', a.feb_2021)
     ) v(month_year, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT month_year, sub,  [c_f],  [type], [F_G], layer, [val] 
FROM   
   (SELECT *  
   FROM t) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (val  FOR month_year IN   
      ([dec_2020], [jan_2021], [feb_2021])  
)AS unpvt;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48b8b/8)